# Check for MATLAB dataset consistency

Tags: matlab, validation, numbers, dataset

In the case of matrices the following command works fine for me every time I want to make sure that its contents are REAL NUMBERS, but always BIGGER THAN ZERO and FINITE. But, it doesn't work for datasets.

```
ispositive =    ( ~isnumeric(batch_data) ...
                | ~all(isfinite(batch_data(:))) ...
                | ~isreal(batch_data) ...
                | ~(any(batch_data(:) <= 0)) );

if (ispositive)

end
```

Any idea on how to modify it?

Comment: Basically, its a certain type of data structure produced by the Statistics toolbox... But, never mind. I found another solution. Thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: By the way, how does your expression for `ispositive` work? You ask for it not being numeric, or not all elements being finite, or not real, or no element lesser or equal than zero.

Comment: suppose dataset is given as cell to you. Have you considered rewriting so it will accept cell input? Alternatively you could use the double function of dataset to convert to a matrix.

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally found an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: @eualin you could also share the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ispositive =    ( ~isnumeric(batch_data) ...
            | ~all(isfinite(batch_data(:))) ...
            | ~isreal(batch_data) ...
            | ~(any(batch_data(:) <= 0)) );
```

This does NOT do what you say.

According to this statement the following are positive:
    batch_data = Inf
    batch_data = -Inf
    batch_data = 'ralph'
    batch_data = 1j;
    batch_data = -1j;

---

Related to what you wrote, this works:

```
positive =  all(isnumeric(batch_data(:)) ...
              && all(isfinite(batch_data(:))) ...
              && isreal(batch_data) ... % isreal breaks convention of is* functions
              && all(batch_data(:) > 0)) ;
```

Comment: `isreal` operate on the entire input (not element-wise), so the `all` surrounding it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Amro thanks for the note about `isreal()`, I did not know that.  One of the big flaws of Matlab I think is its inconsistency.  So many `is*` function report element by element, and then one `isreal` does not?  Because of that I hesitate to edit my answer, I'll edit a comment in at least.